# How to fix the application crash at startup when using 64-bit bass.dll in 64-bit Delphi project?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3, win64, bass.dll

I can't run my 64-bit Delphi application with [the 64-bit version of bass.dll](http://www.un4seen.com/forum/?topic=9038).
I'm using Delphi XE3 to build my application.

Application crashed to start with `0xc000007b`. Debugger Messages:

```
Thread Start: Thread ID: 7692. Process Project1.exe (7444)
Process Start: D:\svn\preplayer\Project1.exe. Base Address: $0000000076DBC500. Process Project1.exe (7444)
Module Load: Project1. Has Debug Info. Base Address: $0000000000400000. Process Project1.exe (7444)
Module Load: ntdll.dll. No Debug Info. Base Address: $0000000076D90000. Process Project1.exe (7444)
Module Load: snxhk64.dll. No Debug Info. Base Address: $0000000070D20000. Process Project1.exe (7444)
Module Load: KERNEL32.dll. No Debug Info. Base Address: $00000000766B0000. Process Project1.exe (7444)
Module Load: KERNELBASE.dll. No Debug Info. Base Address: $000007FEFD4B0000. Process Project1.exe (7444)
Module Load: OLEAUT32.dll. No Debug Info. Base Address: $000007FEFEFC0000. Process Project1.exe (7444)
Module Load: ole32.dll. No Debug Info. Base Address: $000007FEFD660000. Process Project1.exe (7444)
Module Load: msvcrt.dll. No Debug Info. Base Address: $000007FEFE670000. Process Project1.exe (7444)
Module Load: GDI32.dll. No Debug Info. Base Address: $000007FEFD870000. Process Project1.exe (7444)
Module Load: USER32.dll. No Debug Info. Base Address: $0000000076920000. Process Project1.exe (7444)
Module Load: LPK.dll. No Debug Info. Base Address: $000007FEFEE10000. Process Project1.exe (7444)
Module Load: USP10.dll. No Debug Info. Base Address: $000007FEFEE90000. Process Project1.exe (7444)
Module Load: RPCRT4.dll. No Debug Info. Base Address: $000007FEFE9B0000. Process Project1.exe (7444)
Module Load: ADVAPI32.dll. No Debug Info. Base Address: $000007FEFEC90000. Process Project1.exe (7444)
Module Load: SECHOST.dll. No Debug Info. Base Address: $000007FEFEAE0000. Process Project1.exe (7444)
Module Load: VERSION.dll. No Debug Info. Base Address: $000007FEFC300000. Process Project1.exe (7444)
Module Load: COMCTL32.dll. No Debug Info. Base Address: $000007FEFA2B0000. Process Project1.exe (7444)
Module Load: SHELL32.dll. No Debug Info. Base Address: $000007FEFD8E0000. Process Project1.exe (7444)
Module Load: SHLWAPI.dll. No Debug Info. Base Address: $000007FEFEB00000. Process Project1.exe (7444)
Module Load: COMDLG32.dll. No Debug Info. Base Address: $000007FEFD5C0000. Process Project1.exe (7444)
Module Load: WINSPOOL.DRV. No Debug Info. Base Address: $000007FEF96A0000. Process Project1.exe (7444)
Module Load: BASS.dll. No Debug Info. Base Address: $0000000180000000. Process Project1.exe (7444)
Module Load: WINMM.dll. No Debug Info. Base Address: $000007FEFAED0000. Process Project1.exe (7444)
Module Load: MSACM32.dll. No Debug Info. Base Address: $000007FEFAD00000. Process Project1.exe (7444)
```

[BASS for Win64 (x64)](http://www.un4seen.com/forum/?topic=9038)

How can I get it to work ? Does anyone experienced the same problem ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error code 0xc000007b is STATUS_INVALID_IMAGE_FORMAT. The most common cause for that is when the loader attempts to load a 32 bit DLL into your 64 bit process. Use Dependency Walker in profile mode to find out which DLL is at fault.